# facet_wrap log_transforming the axis in one column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a 2 by 2 grid created by `facet_grid` with free scales (see example). I want to have a log scale for the figures in the second row of the grid but not on the first row.

Example code:

```
data("mtcars")

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(y = mpg, x = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~ vs + am, nrow = 2, scales = "free")
```

`scale_y_log10()` seems to do something strange. Is that at all possible or do I have to use something like `grid.arrange`?

Comment: @zx8754's answer is a good and quick way to effectively reach your result. However, as a matter of principle facets are designed to be small multiples with _common scales_. You're therefore kind of rowing up stream. For a neat solution, with separate y-axis labels for example, you'll have to produce separate plots. You can combine them with `grid.arrage`, or have a look `cowplot::plot_grid` for easy alignment.

Answer (score 3):

We could transform then plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# manual transform
plotDat <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mpg = if_else(vs == 1, log10(mpg), mpg), 
         cyl = as.factor(cyl))

# then plot
ggplot(data = plotDat, aes(y = mpg, x = cyl)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ vs + am, nrow = 2, scales = "free")
```

Comment: I guess you'll have to do some smart facet labeling though.